# openCart custom jQuery styling

Tags: jquery, html, css, opencart

I was told by the boss to add a custom style to an `<a>` tag when it is clicked, i thought this will be an easy stuff, but i realised whenever i click on a link in openCart the whole site reloads.
Basicly the class is being added to that `<a>` tag but right after site reloads, and it forgets my jquery addClass() styling. :(

[Live demo](http://borbelykertlabor.hu/webshop/index.php?route=common/home)

jQuery snippet:

```
/* foMenu -bklActive */
$('#menu ul li a').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parents().find("a").removeClass('bklActive');
  $(this).addClass('bklActive');
});
```

Comment: Try adding `return false;` after the `$(this).addClass('blkActive');`

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove all given classes on all `a`-elements in your `#menu` instead of using the siblings method:

```
$('ul li a').on('click', function () {
    $("ul li a").removeClass('bklActive');
    $(this).addClass('bklActive');
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/d9LqD/

**Update**

To get this a bit more dynamically use the `jQuery.fn.parents`-method for that:

```
$('ul li a').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parents().find("a").removeClass('bklActive');
    $(this).addClass('bklActive');
});
```

Comment: thanks, edited my code / stackoverflow thread, but my main problem is that this stiling disappears.

Comment: @AttilaEgyed I think your problem sits on the PHP which generates the menu-structure for you... You have to set the `bklActive`-class via PHP... If you provide your PHP-code here I'll see what I can do for you..

Comment: @Jay Gilford yeah it works on that way, but then the site wont load (:

Comment: I'm sorry but i have no idea which PHP calls this, this is openCart 1.5.4 :$ this is all i know :):)

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=4212#.UTcyUxxWySo

Comment: Thanks but i dont want to spend money on this, probably just need to find that php script somehow, but no idea how. that is why i tagged opencart also :):)